# Parallel Algorithm Analysis: Loops

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, parallel-computing

I have come across what seems to be a collapsed loop.

```
parallel-for i, j = 1...n
```

What would be the work and span/depth/critical path length be of loops like this? Would it be the same as that of the following:

```
parallel-for i = 1...n
  parallel-for j = 1...n
```

**EDIT**:

**Work** = the asymptotic running time of the algorithm on a single core (total computational steps)

**Span**/**depth**/**critical path length** = the asymptotic running time of the algorithm on an infinite number of cores (the point beyond which more parallel processors won't give any performance gains).

Comment: Without knowing what language/formalism this is, my guess is that it's emphasising that every execution of the body is independent. Can you give a little more detail about where this comes from?

Comment: It's a step in a matrix algorithm

`parallel-for i, j, k = 1 to n do
   C[i, j, k] = A[i, k] * B[k, j]`

Comment: Please define the terms *work, span, depth, critical path length* in the frame of your question.

Comment: Added. I took those as standard terms because I've seen them used without definition in parallel programming resources.

Answer (score 1):

The **work** $W(n)$ is the total number of nodes in your computation
graph and the **span** $D(n)$ is the number of nodes on the longest path
of that graph. $T_P(n)$ is the **runtime** of the algorithm
using $P$ processors; $T_1(n) = W(n)$ and $T_\inf(n) = D(n)$.

Suppose your code has the following shape

```
parfor i in range(n):
    parfor j in range(n):
        f()
```

where $f() \in O(1)$ is some function (with side-effects). The keyword
"parfor" means that every loop iteration is independent. There are
$n^2$ independent iterations so in theory $W(n)\in O(n^2)$ and
$T_\inf(n) = D(n)\in O(1)$.

However, the work of starting each $f()$ thread and waiting for its
result must be accounted for. That is, we must implement the "parfor"
keyword. Here is one way:

```
parfor_impl(f, lo, hi):
    if hi - lo <= 1:
        f()
    else:
        mid = (lo + hi) // 2
        spawn parfor_impl(f, lo, mid)
        spawn parfor_impl(f, mid, hi)
        wait
```

where the keywords "spawn" and "wait" launches threads and waits for
previously launched threads' completion respectively. This is a
classical recursive scheme with $W_{parfor} \in O(n)$ and $D_{parfor}
\in O(\log n)$. To get the total runtime (and span) we just add the
runtime of the two nested loops $O(2\log n) = O(\log n)$. We do not
multiply the runtime since the loops run in parallel.

I can highly recommend the "Intro to the Work-Span Model" chapter of
Udacity's [High Performance
Computing](https://learn.udacity.com/courses/ud281) course which
delves deep into this topic.